# Is there a formal phrase for saying that the location of an event changes between two places?

Tags: phrase-requests, formality

The context of my question is the following. I am involved in organization of a conference which is held every year but in two different places (every second year in each of them). What is the best formal way of saying that the location of a recurring event changes between two places? I want to put it on the conference web-page, therefore I need some nice solution.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for their suggestions. It is @smithkm's answer I have decided to use, so I've accepted it as one that best suits what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it has "alternating locations of X and Y" or that it is "alternately held in X and Y".

Comment: It alternates between x and y.

Comment: @WS2 I considered that but it lacks the indication of being located in those places.  It just indicates there is some relationship that alternates between them.  It's probably OK in context but I decided to play it safe with my suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

The two (feasibly more) locations are [**alternating**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prequel%20movie%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22alternating%20venues%22&tbm=bks) or [**rotating venues**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prequel%20movie%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22rotating%20venues%22&tbm=bks).

You might prefer the second version if there are more than two, particularly if they host the event in a regular cycle. And if there's no pattern to the hosting sequence, you might prefer **alternative**.

Comment: I like the sound of rotating venues, although it sounds a bit more active than the actual process.

Comment: @David: How "active" can a *venue* be? It's irrelevant if the process of selecting one is a major activity. All that matters is every venue gets to be host at least sometimes, usually on some kind of regular predictable basis.

Comment: I said I liked it (and up voted it).  It just makes it sound like the place is spinning on it's own access, that was my point.

Comment: @David: I bet if you'd been a Victorian you'd have have been embarrassed / offended / titillated by the sight of a [bare piano leg](http://liberalengland.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/professor-strange-victorians-modesty.html). Practically all language use is figurative, so we the audience have to allow for that and screen out irrelevant connotations. In this case maybe that's easier for me than for you because I'm familiar with both the forms I gave above - on subsequent encounters, you've already done that "screening" before, so habituation homes straight in on the connotations that *are* wanted.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my point. I use rotating in the same manner. It just amuses me to think of the other meanings it could take on. I have no doubt of its usage or even aptitude.  Imagine I said we have a rotating venue and you got there to find it spinning. That is all. No blushing at piano legs or giggling at the tit mouse, just purely amusing imagery.

Comment: I'm speaking of subverting expectation for comedic effect. I've tried to find a good video of this, but they were all beyond lame. There were a few rather funny ones about sex euphemisms but I cannot seem to dredge one up.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternating between venues yearly.**

Answer (score 1):

**The conference is held in X and Y in alternate years.**

You could also mention that it's in X in even years and Y in odd years, or leave the reader to infer that from the fact that the 2014 conference is in X.

Answer (score 0):

In tourism, they talk about twin-centre or dual-centre holidays, I would describe an event happening out of two locations as dual-centre or dual location

Comment: That (to my ear) sounds like the event is *co-hosted* at both locations every year.